# How to view the CQL generated when using Cassandra with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

When using construct of the type

```
public interface TableNameDAO  extends CrudRepository<TableNameModel, String>  {
   List<TableNameModel> findAll();
}
```

how do I view the generated CQL query in the console of the spring-boot app when this gets executed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CQL statements are logged by `CqlTemplate` on `DEBUG` level. Setting the logger `org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql` (Spring Data Cassandra 2.0 and later, use `org.springframework.cassandra.core` for Spring Data Cassandra 1.5.x) to `DEBUG` will report all executed statements:

```
2018-08-13 11:00:31,468 DEBUG | main | org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate | Executing CQL Statement [UPDATE user SET a = 'b';] |
```

Alternatively, you can register a query logger in `Cluster`:

```
Cluster cluster = …;
cluster.register(QueryLogger.builder().build());
```

Log output of [`QueryLogger`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.5/com/datastax/driver/core/QueryLogger.html) is logged to loggers like `com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL` at `DEBUG` level.